# @react-navigation/material-top-tabs not working on tab android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-paper

The material top tabs for react native is working fine on IOS but not on android, here is the video i have recorded of me showing it :
[video](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/e03zdZdX9A8)
The pages are switched when clicked on the tab but only the tabindicator is not working.
The dependencies are all up-to-date,and someone mentioned downgrading react native pager view [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75381036/22658616)but it didnt work.
the code and the version of dependencies:

```
import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import {useTheme} from 'react-native-paper';
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import Masonry from './Masonry'; // Assuming Masonry is a properly defined and exported component

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const BrowseScreen = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: theme.colors.background}}>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarIndicatorStyle: {backgroundColor: 'pink'},
        }}>
        <Tab.Screen name="tab1" component={Masonry} />
        <Tab.Screen name="tab2" component={Masonry} />
        <Tab.Screen name="tab3" component={Masonry} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default BrowseScreen;
```

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^4.3.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^11.2.1",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.3.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.6.1",
    "@react-native-seoul/masonry-list": "^1.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/elements": "^1.3.21",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@shopify/flash-list": "^1.6.3",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.14.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^6.2.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.11.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.8.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.29.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^14.1.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.6.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.23.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.23.6",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "^0.73.18",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.73.1",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.73.2",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "^0.73.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
```

all my import are good and on IOS everything works fine.

Someone has a solution?

Comment: Did you wrap the app in [NavigationContainer](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/#wrapping-your-app-in-navigationcontainer)? If yes, try also to clean android build folder (everything of it) and gradle cache. Delete also the .lock file (yarn or package) and re-download all the packages. Run then metro with reset cache flag. Check also if your device/simulator is not "too old".

Comment: Thank you for your help but I did all you suggested and it's still not working... and i also tried to implement this in my app.js: I nested the toptab navigator inside the tabsgroup which is nested inside HomestackGroup, and NavigationContainer wraps the HomestackGroup, and the problem persists...

Comment: I know that your specified "Masonry" as a well defined component, but still you could try to replace it with almost empty pages without hooks: only Views with different backgrounds. Maybe your custom component is causing some problems with the Tabs? Just guessing. Did you try it also to downgrade all the minor (x.Y.z) versions of the dependencies from navigation?

Comment: thanks I tried them all... none worked lol so I'm switching to flutter haha thank you again for your kind support ❤️